# Possible Safari bug? Calculating wrong height of perspective animated drop down menu

Tags: css, safari

Safari is unable to calculate the correct height of my drop down menu.

I can't figure out what the problem might be, is it a code error or a bug in Safari?

The issue is illustrated with a animated GIF below.

One possible hack, rather than a solution, is to remove `list-style: none;` and replace it with a transparent image. This will make Safari calculate the correct height.

Here's a link to [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YgbVXE)

[image]

```css
nav {
 font-size: 13px;
 background: black;
}

nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

nav a {
 color: #ffffff;
}

nav > ul {
 perspective: 2000px;
}

nav > ul > li {
 position: relative;
}

nav ul li ul {
 position: absolute;
 left: -9999px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform: rotateX(-50deg);
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 transition: transform .25s;
 top: 100%;
 background: black;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
 left: 0;
 transform: rotateX(0);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.php">Main</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 15</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 16</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 17</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 18</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 19</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 20</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 21</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 22</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 23</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: It looks like Safari is calculating the page height before your transition is complete: `transition: transform .25s;`  I'm researching this.

Comment: It works if you remove `list-style: none`, kind of strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the best solution I came up with.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qvzjbo).

```css
nav {
 background: black;
}

nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

nav a {
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #ffffff;
}

nav > ul {
 perspective: 2000px;
 display: flex;
}

nav > ul > li {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 0px;
}

nav ul li ul {
 position: absolute;
 left: -9999px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform: rotateX(-50deg);
 transform-origin: 0 0;
 transition: transform .25s;
 top: 100%;
 background: black;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
 left: 0;
 transform: rotateX(0);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.php">Main 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 13</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 14</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 15</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 16</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 17</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 18</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 19</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 20</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 21</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 22</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 23</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="index.php">Main 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by adding min-height: 525px; to the nav ul li ul element. It's not scrolling properly because the ul is absolute positioned which causes the ul to not expand the container it is in. By adding a min-height it makes sure the container is at least as tall as the menu.

Comment: Thanks but your solution doesn't work if you have dynamic content and multiple main items.

Comment: It does work if you set it according to the longest menu. The problem is you have no content on the page, once you put content and fill up the page none of this will be a problem anymore. The body or any container will not expand according the size of an absolute positioned item, html and css just don't work that way.

Comment: My provided code is just an example, in production the menu exceeds the body height. Create a code snippet and test your code, scroll to the bottom and see how what it looks when the UL exceeds the height of the items. It look bad. Sorry, but your solution is not good. Setting a fixed height on a menu is never a good idea in the first place. Every time you'd add more items to the menu, you'd have to change the height.

Comment: It's not a fixed height, it's a minimum height, but yes you are right that you will have to keep updating it when you add items. Creating a menu that is longer than the body is really bad UX anyway. Like I said, you can either set a min height or make sure the body is longer than the menu. Since the menu is absolutely positioned it will not make the body expand.